# change title color

Tags: color, titles, renewcommand

I use this code to batch modify the title color of a large number of latex files

```
\renewcommand{\title}[1]{\renewcommand{\@title}{\color{\@titlecolor}#1}}
\newcommand{\@titlecolor}{black}
\newcommand{\titlecolor}[1]{\renewcommand{\@titlecolor}{#1}}
\makeatother
```

But I found that the program will get wrong results when the title has optional parameters.

```
\documentclass[reqno]{amsart}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\title}[1]{\renewcommand{\@title}{\color{\@titlecolor}#1}}
\newcommand{\@titlecolor}{black}
\newcommand{\titlecolor}[1]{\renewcommand{\@titlecolor}{#1}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\title[Boundary layer ansatz for the steady MHD equations]{Verification of Prandtl boundary layer ansatz for the steady electrically conducting fluids with a moving physical boundary}

\email{test@mail.com}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

I hope to modify this code to adapt to the situation where there are optional parameters.
Every help and its description is highly welcome.

Comment: Where does the optional argument for `\title` end up in your title? Is it a subtitle? Can you provide a complete minimal document that we can use to replicate your current setup? It should start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`. Can you do that?

Comment: `\title` is defined by the document class so you have not provided any indication of the original definition. The definitions in the standard classes such as `article` do not have an optional argument.

Comment: Sorry, the code was not complete just now, now the complete code has been added

Comment: Erh, that is not how `\title` works in `amsart` you have just killed `\shorttitle`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As so many others, don't put formatting into data holder macros, it never belongs there. Add the formatting to the macro that actually typesets the data.

Looking at the source of `amsarty.cls` we can deduce that within `\maketitle` we go through `\@maketitle` and end up typesetting the title via `\@settitle`, which is defined as

```
\def\@settitle{\begin{center}%
  \baselineskip14\p@\relax
    \bfseries
    \uppercasenonmath\@title
  \@title
  \end{center}%
}
```

thus we can patch this to add color after `\bfseries` therefore this works

```
\documentclass[reqno]{amsart}
\usepackage{xcolor,etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\@titlecolor}{black}
\newcommand{\titlecolor}[1]{\renewcommand{\@titlecolor}{#1}}

\patchcmd\@settitle{\bfseries}{\bfseries\color{\@titlecolor}}{}{\ERROR}


\titlecolor{orange}

\makeatother
\begin{document}

\title[Boundary layer ansatz for the steady MHD equations]{Verification of Prandtl boundary layer ansatz for the steady electrically conducting fluids with a moving physical boundary}

\email{test@mail.com}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```